# The Next() Function Of react infinite scroll is calling without scrolling

Tags: reactjs, redux, infinite-scroll

I have Used react infinite scroll. When I receive the first dataset, the next function works well, but after that, if I perform an action like clicking on an element, then the scroll function is called infinitely, and it refreshes the div data (Elements).

```
<InfiniteScroll
    dataLength={this.state.data.length}
    next={this.getdataForScroll.bind(this)} // the function call as the next function 
    hasMore={hasMoreForInfiniteScroller}
    loader={loaderForInfiniteScroller}
    scrollableTarget="div_search_results">

        {this.renderSearchResults()} // this is function which gives search results

</InfiniteScroll>
```

Here is the Next() function:

```
getdataForScroll = () => {
  this.props.getCompaniesForScroll()
};
```

Is there any possibility to have these kind of issue with infinite scrolls? It is working well for the first time. Can a function in react like the `getdataForScroll()` be called when the component is rendered?

Comment: Hi @Samz, what library is that `InfiniteScroll` from? Also, could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the error you are facing?

Comment: Hi here the Library 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in `next = {this.getdataForScroll.bind (this)}`, switch to `next = {this.getdataForScroll ()}`